# Allure report is not generated

Tags: java, selenium, cucumber, browser-automation, allure

Following is the runner class and the pom.xml files, after running mvn build the allure-results folder is not generating. I am using the allure-cucumber5-jvm with cucumber 5.1.0. I think the allure 5 is compatible with the cucumber 5, please help me on this

```
@CucumberOptions(tags = "@Test", features = {"src/test/java/features"},
        glue = {"com.test.stepdefs"},
        plugin = {"pretty"})
```

Following are the pom details, the cucumber version is 5.1.0

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
        <version>${cucumber-verison}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-picocontainer</artifactId>
        <version>${cucumber-verison}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-testng</artifactId>
        <version>${cucumber-verison}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
        <version>${cucumber-verison}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
        <artifactId>allure-cucumber5-jvm</artifactId>
        <version>2.13.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.6</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
            <configuration>
                <properties>
                    <property>
                        <name>dataproviderthreadcount</name>
                        <value>2</value>
                    </property>
                </properties>
                <argLine>
                    "-javaagent:"${settings.localRepository}/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/${aspectj.version}/aspectjweaver-${aspectj.version}.jar"
                    -Dcucumber.options="--plugin
                    io.qameta.allure.cucumber5jvm.AllureCucumber5Jvm"
                </argLine>

            </configuration>
```